# How can I put a cluster lines in numeric order?

Tags: python, sed, perl, regex, awk

How can I convert this:

```
-foo -bar 42 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 104 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 1 \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
```

To this:

```
-foo -bar 1 \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 42 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 104 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
```

I would like to sort the clusters of lines based on the numeric value after **-bar**

Comment: `cut` and `sort` are your friends...

Comment: Most definitely. I am just uncertain on how to get the entire lines + the extra leading lines

Comment: Any way to simplify this? Like, can we always assume that the first entry of  each group starts with `-`and that the inner entries always don't?

Comment: GREAT question kos, unfortunately, some following lines will have a "-". I edited my question like so. However, the first entry of each group will start with "-foo"

Comment: Last question, is indentation done with tabs? Spaces? In any case, any other sequence of tabs / spaces aside from those used for indentation?

Comment: The indentation is done with 5 spaces, and there will only be 3 "layers" max as shown in the `-bar 42` group (I think that's what you are asking, please let me know otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re, sys
list_of_lines = []
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f.read().split('-foo'):
        if line:
            list_of_lines.append(line)
    for line in sorted(list_of_lines, key=lambda i: int(re.search(r'(?<=-bar )\d+', i).group())):
        print '-foo' + line.rstrip()
```

**Output :**

```
-foo -bar 1 \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 42 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 104 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
```

**How to run :**

Save the file as e.g. `script.py`, make it executable and then pass the file you want the script to opertate on as the first argument:

```
/path/to/script.py /path/to/file.txt
```

If the script and file are on the same directory, then from that directory:

```
./script.py file.txt
```

You can run it without making executable by passing the script as an argument to `python` executable:

```
python2 script.py file.txt
```

Comment: Hey heemayl, thanks for an answer once again, what would I have to change to make it work like so:
/heemayls/script file

Comment: Cool heemayl as a script folder on your system 

Comment: @TuxForLife: I am flattered :D ..check my edits..

Comment: Absolutely outstanding. I really need to learn python, I have tried, but I get lost after a while. You have inspired me to try harder, thank you.

Comment: @TuxForLife: Thats a very big statement, i am no one really to be inspired from :) ..there are many sound people around here, you should take inspiration from them :)....and yeah, python is fun..once you get a grip of it many tasks would be somewhat simpler for you..start learning again :)

Answer (score 1):

The perl way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$filename=$ARGV[0];
open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "cannot open < $filename: $!";

my %hash, my $key;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  if ($row =~ /\-bar\s+([0-9]+)/ ) {
    $key = $1;
  }
  $hash{$key} .= "$row\n";
}

foreach (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%hash) ) {print "$hash{$_}"}
```

Save the script and call the executable (`chmod +x script`) with:

```
script file.txt
```

Output:

```
-foo -bar 1 \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 42 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
          -randomtext=00 "00" \
-foo -bar 104 \
     randomtext=00 "00" \
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, it's great to have a surplus of working methods!